# Visual Studio 2013 Pending Changes does not include newly added item

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

I am currently start using Visual Studio 2017 along with Team Foundation Service that is why this question arise.

1. When I am working with Visual Studio 2013 and add new item to Solution and then do Pending changes from Team Explorer, It does not included newly added item to solution or project.
2. I have sample problem with same scenario in VS 2017.

Actually I want to work with TFS and Visual Studio 2017/2015/2013 but not want to bind solution. Only Team Explorer level binding I want to use.

Comment: do you see green plus sign beside new items?

Comment: What's file you added? Is it in excluded changes? Also check Detected files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you create a new item and then check both in VS2013 and VS2015**, please make sure you are using the same workspace for VS2013 and VS2017.

- In source control explorer, check the workspace is same between VS2013 and VS2017.

[image]

- In pending changes, also check the work space is same as the one in source control explorer.

[image]

**If you create new items separately in VS2013 and VS2015**, please make sure you add items by the same way and options.
For TFVC, there are many ways to add files to source control:

1. File option in VS. In VS -> File -> New -> Project, if you select Add to source Control, it will automatically add the new project in source control ( you can find in pending changes).
2. Source Control Explorer. If you add files or folder in source control explorer, it will automatically add the new items in source control.
3. Add files in the local map copy. If you add files by this way, you need to manually add files to source control, such as VS -> File -> source control -> add items to folder.

Comment: Is that possible to do without bind project to visual studio ? I am only using tem explorer to detect changes

Comment: If you use team explorer, that's still actually bind project to VS. And VS is a convenient IDE for you to connect your project in VSTS/TFS. If you do not want to use VS, you can also use command line https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands.

Comment: Answer is some what helped me. It is something related to point 3. Does it possible to detect changes directly without explicitly using "add items to folder option".  Because We have disconnected environment and somebody add file to csproj then change in csproj detected but newly added file does not comes under change.

Comment: No, you need to add the new fileinto source control, then TFVC can find the changes.

Comment: If you wish then I will another question but my problem is that if I add new file to csproj and csproj already commited so change in that detected by source control but as newly added file not in source control it is not detected. So If someone checkin only csproj because person forgot that he/she added new file then build get failed on TFS side. problem is that project is large so I get to know this very late. Is it any way we can detect this thing early stage without writing anything custom.

Comment: Since it's another question, so you can post a new one, and comment is limited to answer it.

Comment: It seems that you clear the confusion but not answer but still I accept the answer as there is no other solution apart from custom development so I accept the answer.

Comment: I have created another question if you could some help me with that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693189.