# Find Change in CSProj Before Commit without Custom Development

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild

My question is somewhat related to this: [Visual Studio 2013 Pending Changes does not include newly added item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433662)

I have one csproj file that is already checked in. Now somebody add some new file to project like class file or some resource file. As I am working in disconnected to TFS newly added file is not detected as change until I go to source control and add file.

Problem is somebody check-in the CSProj file without new file so at build server it get failed because he/she forgot to add newly added file because it is not detected automatically.

Is there any way we can check integrity of CSProj file before it get check-in so build will not get failed for this reason ?

Note : I want a way without any custom development like Policy or something.

Comment: What kind of workspace you use? Actually, it you are using local workspace, when you are offline(disconnect with TFS server), you could also edit your project at your local computer. When you online again, it will detect those changes you made and you could check them in.

Answer (score 1):

TFS can't check integrity of CSProj file before it gets check-in. You could use a [Gate-check in build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh190718%28v=vs.120%29.aspx#Use%20Automatic%20Build%20Triggers). When you do a check, this build definition will run. If this build succees, it will check in code, if it failes, it won't check in your code. This will give you a remind and force to your add those missing class files.